# Does a Ruby Prime object come with a fixed amount of prime numbers when initialised?

Tags: ruby, primes

When I create a Prime object in Ruby, say `foo = Prime.instance`, does it come with a fixed amount of prime numbers 'preloaded'? If so, how many?

If not, are they dynamically generated if and when required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no pre-generated primes, except for a very small number in [one specific generator](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/prime.rb#L382). That said, you shouldn't depend on even those to be pre-generated, as this is entirely implementation-specific and they could go away at any time.

Comment: There's a second (similar) generator: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/prime.rb#L426. Also, this is being really pedantic, but the code does also "pre-load" the fact that `2` and `3` are prime: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/prime.rb#L35-L36

Comment: Your answer is self-contradictory. The first sentence should just start with "Yes, there are small number ...".

Comment: @sawa "x is true except y" is not contradictory

Comment: The "No" part is contradictory. And the "... expect" part is unnecessary. Anyway, it is confusing. Why do you need to make it complicated?